# Missing content security policy header - issue with chrome and firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, asp-classic, content-security-policy, iis-8.5

I have to fix Missing Content Security Policy Header issue for a Classic ASP application. We have added the below in Web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Post change in IE the application is working, but in Mozilla and Chrome the application is not rendering properly (the css are not loading properly).

If I will add the same in particular asp page too(Response.AddHeader "Content-Security-Policy","default-src"), the same issue is happening.

Please advise.

Comment: Couldn't you just pass it as a meta tag in your HTML head?

Comment: @AdamMcGurk In google developer site I found this - 
The meta tag CSPs preferred delivery mechanism is an HTTP header. It can be useful, however, to set a policy on a page directly in the markup. Do that using a <meta> tag with an http-equiv attribute:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https://cdn.example.net; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none'">

This can't be used for frame-ancestors, report-uri, or sandbox. 
And my application uses iframes. So i think its not possible to use meta tag for me.

Comment: Well if your application uses iFrames, wouldn't that render this http header useless? Also, can you give us more information on the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to better familiarize yourself with what CSP (Content Security Policy) does.  It's actually a good idea to implement from a security standpoint.

Activating a policy without explicitly setting it (in this case "default-src") is the same as setting it to "none". So what your setting does...

`<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src" />`

...is tell the browser to not accept resources from *any* sources. You've said that the default permitted source for this page is "none".  No linking images, no CSS, no scripts.  You've turned it all off.

A better default may be: `default-src self;`

That will allow you to link to CSS and JS files on the same domain. Possibly add `style-src self unsafe-inline;`, but I would not recommend the same for `script-src`.

It totally depends on your site of course. If you're using inline `<script>` and `<style>` tags, look into CSP nonces -- they're pretty easy to use, and more secure than `unsafe-inline`.  If your pages are littered with "onclick"s, you'll have to do some cleanup.  (That type of coding has been discouraged for well over a decade, but you may be dealing with old code, as I do every day.)

Personally, I don't set it at the Server level.  I set it in PHP, which allows flexibility if one particular page needs looser security for some reason (such as using Google Charts, which requires really loose CSP due to `eval()` statements.)  Well, that and you can't use nonces at the Server level, as they have to be generated at the same time as the page.

Comment: A very nice PHP library for working with CSP: https://github.com/paragonie/csp-builder